# HTML5 Main Usage

Tags: html

Previously I'd lay out a main container on an HTML page to wrap most of my body content in. for example, an 'about' page:

```
<header>
    <!--header markup -->
</header>

<div id="container">
    <!--articles, images, etc for the about section -->
</div>

<footer>
    <!--footer markup -->
</footer>
```

would HTML5's `<main>` tag be ideal to take the place of my 'div id="container"' in this case?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main : "The HTML Main Element (<main>) represents the main content of  the <body> of a document or application."

Comment: You can use either <article> or <section> tag.

Comment: At the end of the day they are all still just div containers, this is a patato potato question.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - Not at all. The main element will help an accessibility tool (e.g, a screen reader) user jump directly to the important content of the page in a way that the div element does not. It is therefore a good thing to use when appropriate, as it is in the OP's example.

Comment: Screen reader? really. It probably will probably get him on the top page for google searches too right?

Comment: @Alohci pretty sure that's the aria-role attritbute set, different than actual markup.

Comment: @awesomeq - The <main> element applies the aria role="main" automatically. See http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/ under the section "Browser Support".

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - While it is conceivable that Google's page content analysis might weight content inside the `<main>` element over content outside it, whether it actually does so or not will depend on whether Google's analysis of real world web pages shows that it produces better search results or not. I don't think Google publishes that kind of information, and I wouldn't think that it was in its interest to do so. At best, it would only have a very marginal effect.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith - they aren't just `<div>`'s and there's certainly more to it that spelling preference; they make the content richer and easier to interpret for any mechanical tool that reads web pages (browsers, screen-readers, aggregators, search indexing crawlers) resulting in a better user experience for the human consumer of the content contained - that's what mark up languages are for - any of these tools have an easier time with better defined mark-up than div soup

Comment: You guys read too many books lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word yes.

> The main content of the body of a document or application. The main content area consists of content that is directly related to or expands upon the central topic of a document or central functionality of an application.

[w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-main-element)

See [here for more info](http://html5doctor.com/the-main-element/)

Comment: Thanks! That's what I was thinking, was unsure about use in practice

Answer (score 0):

You should use it for content that is unique to the page. So yes, headers and footers are naturally left out. From there on, it depends what else you have there. If there's a sidebar, for example, with template-loaded content that is common across many pages, you should consider leaving that out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the tag of most important *part* of your website with `<main>`. Mostly `<main>` will replace `<section>`(In your case, `<div>`, and originally it should be `<section>`). Notice that I put emphasis on the word **part** because `<main>` is not for sectioning your document, its purpose is just: point out what's the most important part of your website/application.